# xamarin.forms PCL ThreadPool

Tags: xamarin.forms, threadpool

I need to use ThreadPool in Xamarin.Forms PCL.

Is there support in PCL ?

I know that in android / IOS it exists in native.

Any Package for both IOS and Android that support it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Task.Run it will execute in the thread pool, something like this:

```
var uris = await Task.Run<List<string>>(() =>
    {
        return RegExHelper.ParseLinks(result);
    });
```